# Is blogging considered on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I've yet to see anyone mention blogging.  Is it off-topic?

If not, at what point would blogging questions become off topic?

- Questions about blogging style?
- Questions involving blogging tools?
- Technical questions involving blogging tools (Wordpress themes, installation, etc.)
- Questions about engaging readers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My thoughts:

- *Questions about blogging style*: On-topic, if you mean writing style, how writing techniques may differ from print media, etc. Not so much the graphical style of a blog.
- *Questions involving blogging tools*: Probably on-topic...people have already [asked about writer's software](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9/is-there-a-special-software-for-writers) in general, so I guess it's okay.
- *Technical questions*: Actual installation and troubleshooting of software feels like it should be off-topic (I asked [this question](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31/how-technical-should-questions-on-writer-be) on how technical writers.SE should be).
- *Questions about engaging readers*: If it's about how to write engaging *content*, seems definitely on-topic. Engaging through graphical layouts, colour schemes (or whatever), feels like it should be off-topic.

Another area that I think would be off-topic (because it's a rabbit hole), but I'm not sure: "How do I monetize my blog?"

Comment: I think questions about monetizing blogs should be better put at Wordpress SE or OnStartup SE.

Comment: I agree with your analysis on all points. Installation is a SuperUser or ServerFault issue, depending on the deployment situation, and layout/design is probably one for User Interface or some other design-based SE site.

Comment: Troubleshooting of blogging software can be dealt with on either [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) SE or [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) SE.

Comment: @JFW - Money, that's a good question. I'm going to post [a separate question](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/130/26) about that.

Answer (score 7):

I think blogging *should* be accepted since this is a StackExchange site about writing. However, I think it shouldn't be the focus of this site because, if I interpret it correctly, this site is about general writing (Publishing writing, journalism, ...)

Comment: I agree with this. If we were to decide that blogging was off-topic, what about magazine writing? A blog on a magazine site? We could ask similar questions about self-published eBooks.